# How to capture the output of a command without it displaying in stdout

Tags: ruby, git, stdout, ruby-2.3

How can I capture the output of a command and check for what it says without the command displaying in stdout? For example:

```
  def update!
      `git pull origin master`
      if $?.exitstatus > 0
        puts 'Failed to update'
      elsif $?.success?
        puts 'Upgraded successfully'
      else
        puts 'Already up to date'
      end
    end
```

How can I capture the output of this in order to check whether the command says `up-to date`, an error occurs, or successfully updates? Is there a way to write the output to a file instead of to the console?

---

*Update for answer:*

```
def update!
  update_status = `git pull origin master 2>&1`
  if $?.exitstatus > 0
    puts 'error'
  elsif update_status =~ /Already up-to date/
    puts 'same version as origin master'
  else
    puts 'updated'
  end
end
```

The output for this will always be:

```
[06:44:29 INFO] Updating to newest version..
updated
```

Even if the version is the same as the origin. What I would like to do, if possible, is save the `stdout` of the command to a file and read from that file to discover if the program was updated or not. I think that would be the easiest way to go about doing this.

Comment: Do you want to write tests for your method?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 No, I'm trying to get a update method for a program I have written and want to capture the output of git itself. I just don't know if it's possible to write the output to a file or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the output of the command to a string.

Use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout and thus capture all the output.

```
str = `git pull origin master 2>&1`
if $?.exitstatus > 0
  ...
elsif str =~ /up-to-date/
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: This won't work, when `git` is already up to date it will exit with a status of 0, so the `else` is useless

Comment: I would need to somehow capture the information and check if it says either `updating`, `up-to date`, or some kind of error

Comment: Gotcha, updating!

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Comment: This will still output the command `* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
` I'm trying to prevent that from showing

Comment: What's that do..?

Comment: It redirects stderr to stdout, see comment in my post.

Comment: That's awesome, however this doesn't work as you'd think it would, see my update